# Column titles of gridview in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, gridview

I have created gridview with textbox and button. In textbox I can enter the required number for number of columns I want to add to the grid. The column header should change like t1, t2... Here is my code.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
 if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        griddisplay();
    }
}
public void griddisplay()
{
    con.Open();
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM testclientinfo", con);
    SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
    GridView1.DataSource = dr;
    GridView1.DataBind();
    con.Close();
}

protected void btnadd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int num;
    num = Convert.ToInt32(txtnumber.Text.Trim());
    for (int i = 1; i <= num; i++)
    {


        string name = "t";
        name = string.Concat(name, i);
        BoundField test = new BoundField();
        test.HeaderText = name;
        GridView1.Columns.Add(test);

    }
}
```

Issues are 1.columns are added for second click on add button, when I enter number in textbox and click on add button columns are not added.
2. For example if I enter 2 in textbox t1 & t2 columns are added, again when click on add column header should be t3 & t4 but again t1 and t2 are being added. Please help.

Comment: Answer to the first problem is to put`griddisplay` call in page_load under `if(!IsPostBack)`.

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya Its not working

Comment: You still have to do two clicks for adding columns? Can you update the code which you have changed?

Comment: autogeneratedcolumns of gridview is set to false?

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya yes AutoGenerateColumns="false"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure about problem 1 but problem 2 can be solved as below.

Add a hiddenfield in aspx with id `columnAdded` and set it's value to "0".

```
<input type="hidden" runat="server" value="0" id="columnAdded"/>
```

In code

```
protected void btnadd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int num;
    num = Convert.ToInt32(txtnumber.Text.Trim());
    int addedColumn = Convert.ToInt32(columnAdded.Value);
    for (int i = addedColumn + 1; i <= addedColumn + num; i++)
    {
        string name = "t";
        name = string.Concat(name, i);
        BoundField test = new BoundField();
        test.HeaderText = name;
        GridView1.Columns.Add(test);

    }
    columnAdded.Value = addedColumn + num;
}
```